# How do you enable https for WF Service

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am trying to enable HTTPS binding for a workflow 4.0 hosted service.

What i have been trying out, is changing Enabled Protocols in IIS (current values are http,net.pipe, which gives me **BasicHttpBinding** ad net.pipeBinding but not **"HTTPSBINDING"**), and setting SSL Required to true as well, however

what am i doing wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click "Default Web SIte" or whatever your site is in iiS 7 and then click "Bindings". Add HTTPS on port 443.